# Synchronized method not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have java code with a method that should not be executed by two threads concurrently.

```
package runnableThread;
public class CompteEnBanque {
      private int solde = 100;

      public int getSolde(){
        if(this.solde < 0)
          System.out.println(solde);

        return this.solde;
      }

      public synchronized void retraitArgent(int retrait){
        solde = solde - retrait; 
        System.out.println("Solde = " + solde);                 
      }
    }

package runnableThread;
public class RunImpl implements Runnable {
  private CompteEnBanque cb;
  private String name;

  public RunImpl(CompteEnBanque cb, String name){
    this.cb = cb;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
      if(cb.getSolde() >= 2){
        cb.retraitArgent(2);
        System.out.println("Retrait effectuÃ© par " + this.name);                       
      }                       
    }               
  } 
}
```

and here is my main()

```
package runnableThread;
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompteEnBanque cb = new CompteEnBanque();

        Thread t = new Thread(new RunImpl(cb, "marie"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RunImpl(cb, "philippe"));
        t.start();
        t2.start();
      }
    }
```

Normally, the balance (solde in my source code), should never be negative, however, when I execute this code, I get negative values. I did not understand if **synchronized**  worked well or not.

here are some outputs

```
Retrait effectuÃ© par marie
Solde = 0
Retrait effectuÃ© par marie
Solde = -2
Retrait effectuÃ© par philippe
-2
```

Comment: The check on the current value of your number is _outside_ your synchronized method. That allows the number to be updated by another thread between the point where the check is done, and the point where the synchronized method is entered.

Comment: Everything actually does work as expected: since `solde` is never synchronized, one thread is not guaranteed to see the value that another thread changed, or another thread could read the value before other thread had changed it, but it will enter synchronized block after the another thread completed modifying it. You are looking for errors in the wrong place: testing for how synchronized keyword works (and for Java Memory Model in general) is so extensive that it's far more common that you misuse it than that you run into a big there.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the solde value outside of a synchronized block.

To read the correct value you need the updates to solde to "happen before" reading it.  This is only guaranteed if both the write and the read are both inside blocks synchronized on the same object.

Also in Run there is no synchronization around the if statement so solde may have changed between checking the value is >=2 and decrementing the value.